# Force a user to select from JQuery UI Autocomplete and populate a hidden field after selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a large HTML form that contains many fields that need an autocomplete for accounts. I tag these fields with the class AccountLookup and jQuery does the dirty work for the autocomplete:

```
$(".AccountLookup").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Lookup.asmx/GetAccounts",
            data: "{ 'Search': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.Value
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

Now, when a user selects something from the autocomplete I need it to populate a hidden field just BEFORE the tagged input field; probably using something like:

```
$(this).prev().val(item.Key);
```

How do I incorporate this functionality? Also, how do I force a user to select from the auto complete? (All the values are pre-defined, the user cannot add new ones.)

**EDIT:**
As far as I understand from inspecting the DOM, the select option is currently filling in the hidden form field.

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).prev().val(ui.item.key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".AccountLookup").autocomplete({
   /*...*/
}).result(function(event, item) {
   $(this).prev().val(item.Key);
});
```

You could also use a [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to ensure that the field is populated.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old post--- but I ran into it in trying to solve a similar problem (forcing the user to select an item from the list)...

```
        $("#ac").autocomplete({
            source: function (req, resp) {
                   //add code here...
            },
            select: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).next().val(ui.item.id);
            },
            change: function (ev, ui) {
                if (!ui.item)
                    $(this).val("");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

for force selection, you can use ["change" event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)  of Autocomplete

```
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if(!ui.item){
                    //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                    // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                    //so clear the item for force selection
                    $("#tags").val("");
                }

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the selection action, try using the `formatItem` option.  You can format each result to have an onclick event that will populate the other textbox.

For the forcing to select from autocomplete, you need to use the `mustMatch` option.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

Comment: I tried using the mustMatch option, but it doesn't seem to be working. I can still input values not defined by the server and submit the form.

Comment: The jQuery *UI* Autocomplete DOES NOT have the "mustMatch" option. I am using a completely different plugin from the one you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem quite awhile ago and some post helped me along with it.  I have since modified the code as I found that there were cases I wanted one or more fields to fill in from the information returned.  In the select option of the autocomplete I added a function.

```
select: function (e, ui) {ReSetField({'txtID':'id','txtPrice':'price' [,etc...]}, ui)  }
```

The function "**ResetFields**" then takes in a JSON list of element names paired with **fieldnames** and uses the **fieldnames** to match the **elements** in the ui object.  The value can then be pulled from the ui item and put into the html element.

```
    function ReSetField(_flds, _vals) {
  //Set up the flds to be reset with values passed in.  
  try {
    if (_flds != undefined) {
      if ($.type(_flds) == 'string') {
        _flds = JSON.parse(_flds);
      };
      var _fld = null;
      var _val = '';
      $.each(_flds, function (index) {
        if (index.length > 0) {
          _fld = '#' + index;   //Set the forms field name to set  
          _val = _flds[index]; //Pick up the field name to set the fields value 
          $fld = $(_fld);
          $fld.val(_vals.item[_val]); //Set the fields value to the returned value             
          }
        }
      })
    };
  }
  catch (e) {
    alert('Cannot set field ' + _fld + '.');
  } 
}
```

By sticking the "**fieldlist**" into the HTML element as an attribute like "**fieldlist"** and using a class like **"comboBox"** I can then use a single function to find all ComboBox elements and set up the autocomplete on a form reducing the amount of code required to handle 2 or more lookups on a form.